# Multiple Choice Question: Let f be holomorphic on D with $ f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $ f(\frac{1}{2}) = 0 $, where $ D = \{ z : |z|\leq 1 \}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $ f : D \rightarrow D $ be holomorphic with $ f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$  and $ f(\frac{1}{2}) = 0 $, where 
$ D = \{ z : |z|\leq 1 \} $. Please suggest which of the following can be correct ..

1. $ |f'(0)|\leq \frac{3}{4}$.
2. $ |f'(1/2) |\leq \frac{4}{3}$.
3. $ |f'(0)|\leq \frac{3}{4}$ and $ |f'(1/2)|\leq \frac{4}{3}$.
4. $ f(z)=z$, $ z\in D$

Please help.

Comment: Are you sure you told us the whole question?  There isn't an additional assumption, like $f(D) \subseteq D$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Thanks for pointing out the mistake. I have edited now.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: Try some polynomials....

Hints to edited question: note that $f(f(0)) = 0$.  Schwarz's Lemma may be useful.
Also consider what fractional linear transformations take $D \to D$ with $0 \to 1/2$ and $1/2 \to 0$.

Comment: @preeti: Liouville's theorem does not apply, here. Entire means holomorphic on $\C$, not just on a function's domain of definition.

Comment: @CameronBuie: Thanks for the help.

Comment: Further help needed. $f(z)={2\over 3}z(z-{1\over 2})$ is one such with $|f'(0)|=|f'({1\over 2})|={1\over 3}$. No conclusion can be made from here.

Comment: One what? The fractional linear transformation $\phi(z) = \dfrac{2z-1}{z-2}$ takes $D$ onto $D$ and interchanges $0$ and $1/2$.  So (with $f$ as in the question) $f \circ \phi$ takes $D$ into $D$, $0 \to 0$ and $1/2 \to 1/2$.  By Schwarz's lemma, $f \circ \phi(z) = z$, i.e. $f = \phi^{-1} = \phi$.

Comment: $f(f(0))=0$ then by scwarz lemma $|f(f(z))|\leq |z|$ and $|(f\circ f)'(0)|\leq 1$..... $(f\circ f)'(x)=f'(f(x))f'(x)\Rightarrow |(f\circ f)'(0)|=|f'(\frac{1}{2})f'(0)|\leq 1$ this says that if $|f'(\frac{1}{2})|\leq \frac{3}{4}$ then $|f'(0)|\leq \frac{4}{3}$ Infact for $a,b >0$ we have if $|f'(\frac{1}{2})|\leq \frac{a}{b}$ then $|f'(0)|\leq \frac{b}{a}$ but then how do i say that $|f'(\frac{1}{2})|\leq \frac{3}{4}$ :O please help me in this case...

Answer (score 4):

First you should recall the following result:
Suppose that $\displaystyle f$ is analytic on the unit disc ∆=$\{z:|z|<1\}$ and satisfies the following conditions 
    $|f(z)| \leq 1$
    $f(a)=b$ for some $a,b \in $∆ then 
$|f'(a)| \leq (1-|f(a)|^2)/(1-|a|^2 )$.
In our problem first you take $a=0$ and $b=1/2$ and apply the above result you will get the first option in your problem. For the second option take $a=1/2$  and $b=0$. For your problem  options (a), (b) and (c) are true

Answer (score 3):

Schwarz Picks Lemma says $|f'(z)|\le {1-|f(z)|^2\over 1-|z|^2}$ says $1,2,3$ are Correct