# $f:\mathbb D\rightarrow \mathbb D$ be holomorphic with $f(1/2)=0$ and $f(0)=1/2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb D\rightarrow \mathbb D$ be holomorphic with $f(1/2)=0$ and $f(0)=1/2,$ where $\mathbb D=\{z:|z|<1\}.$ Then which of the following statements are correct?

(a) $|f'(0)|\leq 3/4,$

(b) $|f'(1/2)|\leq 4/3,$

(c) $|f'(1/2)|\leq 4/3$ and $|f'(0)|\leq 3/4,$

(d) $f(z)=z$ for $z\in \mathbb D.$

by Schwarz-Pick Lemma $|f'(z)|\le {1-|f(z)|^2\over 1-|z|^2}$ we get $|f'(0)|\le {3\over 4}$ and $|f'(1/2)|\le {4\over 3}$ so  so $a,b,c$ are true, but I don't know how to prove or disprove $d$ could anyone tell me? here $f(0)\ne 0$ so I am not able to use Schwarz-Pick Lemma directly.

Comment: Is there a typo in (d)? 'cause otherwise, since $f(0) \neq 0$ and $0 \in \mathbb{D}$, (d) is obviously false, no?

Comment: ooops sorry by the given condition $f(z)=z$ is automatically false as $f(z)=z\Rightarrow f(0)=0$,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Choice Question: Let f be holomorphic on D with $ f(0) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $ f(\frac{1}{2}) = 0 $, where $ D = \{ z : |z|\leq 1 \}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156615/multiple-choice-question-let-f-be-holomorphic-on-d-with-f0-frac12-a)

Comment: Is d) asking for the existence of a fixed point, $f(z)=z$ for some (but not all) $z\in \Bbb D$?

Answer (score 1):

How about $f(z)=\frac{2z-1}{z-2}$?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(z)=1/2 - z$ then $f(1/2)=0$ and $f(0)=1/2$.  $|f'(0)|=1$ option 1 is false,  now $|f'(1/2)|=1<4/3$ so optn b is correct,  check similarly

Comment: Your $f(-\frac34)=\frac54$ is far outside $\Bbb D$.

Comment: Yaa bcoz no 1 is not correct,  thts why,  i have given a way to know which is correct one

Comment: No, your function does not satisfy the basic condition $f(\Bbb D)\subset \Bbb D$, $\Bbb D=\{z:|z|< 1\}$.. Thus all conclusions are invalid.